# ActiveRecord query where with id discards the content after dash

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I just encountered something rather surprising with the `where` method. When I query something like `MyModel.where(id: '121-fake')`, it gets translated to `id = 121` in SQL, i.e. ActiveRecord appears to remove what's after the dash. This seems to only happen when I query with `id`. Can anyone help point me to where this is implemented? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` field is probably of an integer type, so `ActiveRecord` basically casts the parameter to an integer by calling [`to_i`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i):

```
 '121-fake'.to_i # -> 121
```